# ORing true with some function

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Supposed I have a method `fun()`

```
boolean fun()
{
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    return true;
}
```

I also have a variable `a`

```
boolean a = true;
```

Now if I write

```
boolean b = a || fun();
```

will Java evaluate the right hand side of `||` or will it stop (since `a` is already `true`, so the answer is always going to be `true` and hence it doesn't evaluate the right hand side of `||`).

Comment: Isn't it easier to try it?

Answer (score 4):

See documentation from oracle:

> The Conditional Operators
>
> The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR operations on two boolean expressions. 
>   These operators exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is evaluated only if needed.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

So, java will NOT evaluate the `fun()` expression here, since the "short-circuit" `a` already determines the final value.

If one needs `fun()` to be evaluated, a quick fix can be as following:

```
boolean b = fun() || a;
```

or

```
boolean funValue = fun();
boolean b = a || funValue;
```

Comment: what if i want to evaluate the right hand side function.. what should i do ?

Answer (score 2):

Java will not evaluate the right expression.
The same goes for `&&` in case the first expression evaluates to `false`.

This is required, so you can do things like:

```
if (a != null && !a.isEmpty()) {
    //...
}
```